# State Management trying Restorabletextedingcontrollers but just not working. Trying to save state when leaving app or going from page to page

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, state-management

I have tried many tutorials with different ways of saving state. The "Restorabletexteditingcontroller" seems to be a good match, i have tried restorationmixen with buckets cannot get that to work.
Any help would be welcome thanks all.

I have tried this below
The errors i cannot seem to fix.

Ill add the code then the corresponding errors bellow the code thanks all:

```
// TODO Implement this library.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:last/navbar.dart';
//import 'package:last/main.dart';
//import 'package:tca/navbar.dart';
//import 'package:tca/main.dart';
//import 'package:tca/pages/forth_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(restorationScopeId: "root", home: AddTwoNumbers6()));
}

class AddTwoNumbers6 extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers6({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddTwoNumbers6> createState() => _AddTwoNumbers6State();
}

class _AddTwoNumbers6State extends State<AddTwoNumbers6> with RestorationMixin {
  final int value = 0;
  List<RestorableTextEditingController> roundOneFields = [];
  List<RestorableTextEditingController> roundTwoFields = [];
  int roundOneResult = 0;
  int roundTwoResult = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    roundOneFields = List.generate(
        20, (index) => RestorableTextEditingController(text: '0'));
    roundTwoFields = List.generate(
        20, (index) => RestorableTextEditingController(text: '0'));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sixth Shooter'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(25))),
      ), // This is how you can add an appBar.
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R1 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundOneFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 24,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundTwoFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                          roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                      roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                          roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text("Back"),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Navbar())))
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult Total = ${roundOneResult + roundTwoResult}",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  @override
  // TODO: implement restorationId
  String? get restorationId => "page1";

  @override
  void restoreState(RestorationBucket? oldBucket, bool initialRestore) {
    registerForRestoration(
        roundOneFields as RestorableProperty<Object?>, "round1");enter image description here
        roundTwoFields as RestorableProperty<Object?>, "round2");
    // TODO: implement restoreState
  }
}

Errors
enter image description here
```